# What should our logo and site design look like?

Tags: discussion

Perhaps this is a little premature but it's one of the [7 questions we should be asking](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/).

What would be an appropriate logo to use for a WorldBuilding site? What is recognisable, will work alongside the other SE sites and be eye catching to visitors of the What's Hot list?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because, despite that out-of-date blog post, it's way too early for this discussion.  See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/201776/162102, http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/223674/162102.

Comment: Totally agree with Monica. There's no point talking about logo or design, if we're not sure, if we're going to go any further than private beta, right? :]

Comment: Happy with that, one more vote to close 

Answer (score 4):

My suggestion would be to look to the [Magratheans](http://hitchhikers.wikia.com/wiki/Magrathea) and think about a partially constructed planet. Perhaps something like wikipedia

[image]

I like the idea of the globe being peiced together.

Comment: So you think we should rip off Wikipedia's trademark?

Answer (score 4):

It's far too early to be thinking about this. That 7 questions post is out of date. The site will change and be defined between now and when it gets out of beta. And when it does the logo and site design will be done by the staff at stack exchange.

Comment: is it still too early?  worldbuilding seems to have taken off.  if it is no longer too early, perhaps we can steal this image from the science fiction and fantasy folks: http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/5355

Answer (score 3):

I would vote for a half drawn map

Comment: perhaps with the map features spelling out the site name (or the first letter or two in it).